# How to write conditional loop structure in a function based on input passed through that function

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation, functional-style

I know the question is rather vague so, here is what I am trying to do:

Lets say we have the following function: `color[data_,variableInputs_]. Now what I want this function to do is loop over the data based on what the input variables are. Suppose, I have the following possible input variables:

```
"red"
"blue"
"green"
"orange"
```

Each input variable corresponds to a particular row in the data that I would like to loop over. Thus I want to write a function that will loop over which ever variable I pass into the function, where:

```
"red" -> data[[i,1]]
"blue" -> data[[i,2]]
"green" -> data[[i,3]]
"orange" -> data[[i,4]]
```

Without writing out a horrible nested `If` functions for all the various permutations of what the inputs may be. So if someone writes:

```
output = color[data,{"green","orange"}]
```

I would want the function to look like:

```
color[dataInput_,variableInputs_]:=(
 Table[{dataInput_[[i,3]],dataInput_[[i,4]]},{i,Length@dataInput}]
  )
```

Or if

```
output = color[data,{"blue"}]
```

then I would just have

```
color[dataInput_,variableInputs_]:=(
 Table[{dataInput_[[i,2]]},{i,Length@dataInput}]
  )
```

In principal I'm looking for a way to write in mathematica

```
color[dataInput_,variableInputs_]:=(
 Table[{"option_red","option_blue","option_green","option_orange"},{i,Length@dataInput}]
  )
```

where the option are whatever combination of inputs one can put in, without making use of nested `If` statements to account for each permutation of inputs. The order of inputs need not matter.

I hope I have explained this clearly enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing there are easier ways to do this, but this is the best I could think of:

We'll use an association to translate colors to integers. Here, we'll assume that "*red*" corresponds to 1, "*blue*" corresponds to 2 etc just like in the example in question.

```
(* making switch Listable means that switch[{"red", "blue"}] evaluates to
   {switch["red"], switch["blue"]} *)
SetAttributes[switch, Listable]

With[{sw = <|"red" -> 1, "blue" -> 2, "green" -> 3, "orange" -> 4|>},
  switch[color_] := sw[color]
]
```

As an example of how switch works, we evaluate `switch[{"red", "blue"}]` to get

> ```
> {1, 2}
> ```

as expected (in the question we have that `"red" -> data[[i,1]]` and `"blue" -> data[[i,2]]`).

Now, it's just a matter of defining the desired `color` function by making use of `switch`:

```
color[data_, variableInputs_] := Part[data, All, switch[variableInputs]]
```

Notice, how we've opted for `Part` instead of using `Table`. It could have been done with `Table` too, but it feels better having `Part` picking parts off of `data`.

Now we can test `color` with input a $3\times 4$ symbolic array of `data`. Evaluating the following

```
With[{data = Array[a, {3, 4}]},
  color[data, {"red", "blue"}]
]
```

returns

> ```
> {
>    {a[1, 1], a[1, 2]}, 
>    {a[2, 1], a[2, 2]}, 
>    {a[3, 1], a[3, 2]}
>   }
> ```

as expected (hopefully).

Comment: Since this is a part of what i do in the function, but which is irrelevant to the question. I would need it in a `Table` structure. I thus modified what you did slightly to use your answer in a way that suits me. But It would be great if your answer used the `Table` implementation. I am happy to mark this as an answer nonetheless.

Comment: first off, I'm really happy you found my answer helpful! thanks for accepting it, too! As far as `Table` is concerned, in my experience-and as a general approach- it is *not* considered good practice to use iteration to get parts of expressions. This is what `Part` is for. You could do something like `Table[dataInput[[i, switch[variableInputs]]], {i, Length@dataInput}]` but that is what `Part[dataInput, All, switch[variableInputs]]` does better; for the toy example of the question, using them interchangeably is probably OK, but in general `Part` is more efficient at deconstructing expressions.